# Powershell: loop for equivalent

Tags: powershell

Currently, I'm performing this command on linux shell:

```
for binary in $(curl -s -X GET "${FHIR_SERVER}/\$export-poll-status?_jobId=${JOB_ID}" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" | jq -r ".output[].url"); \
  do wget --header="Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" ${binary} -O ->>patients-pre.json;
done
```

Is there any way to get this on powershell?

Comment: PowerShell (Core) is a cross-platform environment. Are you looking for a true cross-platform solution, or is a solution that relies on standard utilities available on a _given_ platform - such as Linux distros - acceptable?

Comment: @mklement0 - Are you inferring that PowerShell is not truly cross-platform?  This question is coming from someone who hasn't played with it at all on Linux.

Comment: @T-Heron. How do you reconcile your claim with my previous statement of  "PowerShell (Core) is a cross-platform environment"? My point was: A cross-platform shell can be used in one of two ways: (a) In a platform-_specific_ way, relying on _a given platform's native abilities_ or (b) in a truly platform-_agnostic_ way, using only features available on _all supported platforms_. Needless to say, (b) either requires more work or may not even be possible, depending on the use case. (a) requires specifying _which platform should be targeted_.

Comment: @T-Heron, also, in the future, please refrain from gratuitous ad-hominem statements such as "is coming from someone who hasn't played with it at all on Linux". They add nothing to the conversation and only serve to antagonize.

Comment: The official names are `pwsh.exe` which is `Powershell` (without core in the name) verses `powershell.exe` which is `WindowsPowershell` The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) follow this

Comment: @ninMonkey: Yes, _on Windows_ the executable name distinguishes the two editions available there: `powershell.exe` is the executable of the legacy, Windows-only, comes-with-the-OS _Windows PowerShell_ edition (versions up to v5.1), whereas `pwsh.exe` is the executable of the install-on-demand, cross-platform PowerShell (Core) (version starting with v6). On _non-Windows_ platforms,  the install-on-demand, cross-platform PowerShell (Core)  is the _only_ edition available, as executable `pwsh`.

Comment: @ninMonkey:  Thus, the question as to what scenarios need to be supported for a given use case can be refined to: (a) all platforms and - on Windows - both editions, (b) all platforms and - on Windows - PowerShell (Core) only, (c) Windows-only, Windows PowerShell-only, (d) Windows-only, both editions, (e) Windows-only, PowerShell (Core) only.

Comment: Also: (f) non-Windows - i.e., Unix-like platforms - as a group (macOS, Linux), (g) each of those platforms individually, which in the case of Linux can mean any number of distros with differing native utilities. Leaving aside that for any given platform its specific version number may matter.

Comment: Mklement0 - My comment "This question is coming from someone who hasn't played with it at all on Linux." was simply stating a fact - there was nothing ad hominem about it and it definitely wasn't meant to serve to antagonize.  The fact that you either took it as such, or *felt* that you could take it as such, or that others could, is a completely unnecessary psychoanalysis.  I would stick to strictly answering about coding if I were you, and leave the guesswork of the intentions of the author out of it.

Answer (score 2):

While not knowing exactly the format of your incoming json, I'd use something like this in powershell / pwsh:

```
curl ... | % { wget (convertto-json $_).output.url } >> patients-pre.json
```

The `%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object` which will iterate over objects (or lines of text) sent from the left side of the pipe. Powershell is interesting because when using the pipe symbol, there's an implicit `for` / `do` / `done` operation going on.

curl is on all modern versions of windows, so you don't need to change that. wget isn't, but you could install it, or use curl again.

If you want to go full powershell, look at invoke-restmethod ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2 ). This can do the jobs of both curl and wget in your example, and also automatically handle json returns to give you a structured object instead of text (which is what convertto-json is doing above.)

Comment: Also see the `gh` command line utility [https://cli.github.com/manual/gh](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh) It 1] is made for scripting (whether bash/powershell/etc)  2]  simplifies / handles authenticating for the github API 3] has a `--json` parameter, making it easy to parse and 4] has `jq` queries built-in